# Tracker computation not working in production

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-tracker

I have a `Tracker.autorun` function:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    console.log('tst1');
    if(Meteor.user()) {
        Router.go('MyRouteName');
    }
    else {
        Router.go('Route2');
    }

});
```

When I run my meteor app with production, this function doesn't work. Error printed on console is:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:  'e5f8fe47959145548e982acc170a59633baa3fe3.js?meteor_js_resource=true'.

How to proceed?

Comment: Production command I am runing:   sudo meteor --settings server/settings.json --production

Comment: just an error in my post. changed it

Comment: Ah, very well, deleting my previous comment then. Can you try and get more data on the error, for example by wrapping this in a `try..catch` block? What browser are you testing this into?

Comment: I am using google chrome. trying to resolve the error

Comment: Having an actual exception name / line would really help solving this issue yes. You may also want to check the [help], particularly what is a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem. Apparently firefox debugger (firebug) is better than chrome debugger. I was using a var which was undefined in the onCreated function. Hence the code never reached the autorun part.